# Line and points in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P_0 = (1,0,-2)$ and let $\ell$ be the line that goes through  $P_1 = (1,1,1)$ and $P_2 = (3,2,6)$. Find the coordinates for a point $P$ on $\ell$ such that $P_0$ and $P$ are orthogonal to $\ell$.

**Update: Is this attempt a correct one? I have no solutions to check with.**

Attempt: 
[image]

Comment: If you want good answers at least write the problem in $\LaTeX$

Comment: Your work looks correct. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Rustyn, Actually, the only good question on this page is _your_ question. :)  But I think jacob just wants reassurance that he's on the right track.